# Error Icon to be displayed within the textbox

Tags: devexpress, devexpress-windows-ui

I am validating the input of my text field, which is of TextEdit type, using the Validating event. But the error icon is being displayed outside of the text field (second pic) rather than within it (first pic).

I've tried ErrorIconAlignment and it doesn't work. The icon is still being displayed outside of the text. Are there any other ways to have it displayed within the text field?

[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

there is not a property allowing that.

but you can do this with the following code:
I created 2 buttons, 1 `setErrorButton` for set error an 2nd button for clear error with the `SetError` method, unwanted method `CreatePictureEdit`

```
private void setErrorButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SetError(textEdit1, "Error1");
    textEdit1.Properties.MaskBoxPadding = new Padding(12, 0, 0, 0); //to put the cursor after the error image
}

private void clearErrorButto_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SetError(textEdit1, "");
    textEdit1.Properties.MaskBoxPadding = new Padding(0, 0, 0, 0);
}

public static void SetError(Control ctrl, string errorText)
{
    Form f = ctrl.FindForm();
    if (errorText == string.Empty)
    {
        if (ctrl.Tag != null && ctrl.Tag is PictureEdit)
        {
            f.Controls.Remove(ctrl.Tag as PictureEdit);
            return;
        }
        else
            return;
    }
    PictureEdit edit = CreatePictureEdit(ctrl, errorText);
    f.Controls.Add(edit);
    ctrl.Tag = edit;
    edit.BringToFront();

}

private static PictureEdit CreatePictureEdit(Control ctrl, string errorText)
{
    PictureEdit edit = new PictureEdit();
    Image image = BaseEdit.DefaultErrorIcon;
    edit.BorderStyle = DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.BorderStyles.NoBorder;
    edit.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
    edit.Image = image;
    edit.ToolTip = errorText;
    edit.ToolTipIconType = DevExpress.Utils.ToolTipIconType.Error;
    edit.Properties.SizeMode = DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.PictureSizeMode.Squeeze;
    edit.Location = new Point(ctrl.Bounds.Left + 3, ctrl.Bounds.Y + 1);
    edit.Size = new Size(image.Width, ctrl.Bounds.Height - 2);
    edit.BackColor = Color.White;
    return edit;
}
```

you can change the location property values and size of the image if the icon is not adjusted properly on the `TextEdit`